# How to calculate a conditional PDF in mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

## What is an elegant way of calculating this result (programmatically) in mathematica?

Let $X$ be a random variable with PDF

$$f_{X}(x) =
\begin{cases}
x/4,  & \text{if $1<x\leq3$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Let $A$ be the event $\{X\geq2\}$

> Find $f_{X|A}(x)$

---

#### Here is the answer done manually for convenience:

$$f_{X|A}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{f_{X}(x)}{P(A)},  & \text{if $2\leq x\leq3$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$P(A)=P(X\geq2)=\int_{2}^{3}{f_{X}(x) dx}=5/8$$

$$\implies f_{X|A}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2x}{5},  & \text{if $2\leq x\leq3$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

#### I am looking for a programmatic solution that utilizes `\[Conditioned]` or something else as high-level.

`TransformedDistribution` and `ProbabilityDistribution` look like promising avenues, but I am unable to state my problem in terms of them.

I know I could write out the problem explicitly in low level code. But I am looking for an implicit, declarative implementation. Surely mathematica with all its high level abstraction power can do this?

---

here is a failed attempt

```
A = X >= 2;
conditionalDist = TransformedDistribution[X \[Conditioned] A, X \[Distributed]ProbabilityDistribution[x/4, {x, 1, 3}] ] ;
PDF[conditionalDist, y]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use combination of [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) and [`TruncatedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TruncatedDistribution.html) as follows:

```
f[x_] := x/4
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 1, 3}];
td = TruncatedDistribution[{2, Infinity}, dist];

PDF[td, x]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{2 x}{5} & 2<x<3 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
Probability[Conditioned[x <= t, x > 2], Distributed[x, dist]] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  1 & t\geq 3 \\
>  \frac{1}{5} \left(t^2-4\right) & 2<t<3
> \end{cases}$

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method that uses the CDF to directly define the desired distribution and which might be a bit more intuitive/self-evident:

```
f[x_] := x/4
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 1, 3}];

ProbabilityDistribution[
 {
   "CDF", 
   Probability[x < y \[Conditioned] x > 2, x \[Distributed] dist]
 },
 {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}
];
```

> ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{(2*\[FormalX])/5, 2 < \[FormalX] < 3}}, 0], {\[FormalX], -Infinity, Infinity}]

In other words: we just compute the CDF with `Probability` and then plonk it into `ProbabilityDistribution` while telling it that it's a CDF rather than a PDF. This is a useful trick to keep in mind, since the CDF is sometimes easier to work with since it's a proper probability.

Comment: nice! (I felt that there must be a more direct way out there!)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes "compact" can be considered elegant:

```
(x/4)/Integrate[x/4, {x, 2, 3}]
(* (2 x)/5 *)
```

If you need it in terms of *Mathematica*'s `ProbabilityDistribution`:

```
d = ProbabilityDistribution[(x/4)/Integrate[x/4, {x, 2, 3}], {x, 2, 3}]
PDF[d, x]
```

[image: Conditional density]

```
CDF[d, x]
```

[image: Conditional distribution function]

Answer (score 2):

I learned from @kglr that `Probability` can give you a conditional CDF.
One can take the derivative of this to compute the desired conditional PDF.

```
A = X >= 2;
conditionalCDF = Probability[X <= y \[Conditioned] A, X \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[x/4, {x, 1, 3}]];
D[conditionalCDF, y]
```